# How to make the background fixed and make the content inside it to scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've created an background of grid line boxes using linear gradient in NextJS. It looks like,

```
<body className={"bg"}>
        <motion.div
          className="outer-circle"
          variants={variants}
          animate={cursorVariant}
        >
          <div className="cursor"></div>
        </motion.div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="max-w-[1000px] mx-auto py-2 px-3 mt-5">{children}</div>
      </body>
```

The "bg" class looks like,

```
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.6) 1px,
      transparent 1px
    ),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.6) 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

But when the content gets more. It is not scrolling since the position is fixed for body. How to make the content alone scrollable with the fixed background. Any ideas would be appreciated.
The bg looks like,
[image]

Comment: Instead of using  `position: fixed`, why not use `background-attachment: fixed;`?

Comment: @AmauryHanser It worked. I was not aware of this property but now onwards. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Be wary of background-position fixed on Safari IOS, it has some bugs. See caniuse.com

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks, I wasn't aware as it's not something I use often!